# Find $N$ and $M$ in $S × N + (S + 1) × M = T$ when all variables are integers

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integers

I want to calculate the number of frames found in an MP3 file.

The MP3 file format allows you to closely approximate a bit rate per second by breaking down the audio data in blocks of $S$ or $S + 1$ bytes. My problem is to find how many blocks of size $S$ and how many blocks of size $S + 1$ I need to have to precisely match the total size $T$ of a file.

This comes out as the following equation:

$$\large{(S, N, M, T) \in \Bbb Z^{4}, S N + (S + 1) M = T}$$

I know $S$ and $T$, I need to find $N$ and $M$ knowing that all the numbers are elements of $\Bbb Z$ (i.e. integers). We also know that $T \gg S$.

Note: it is also assumed that $T$ is correct and indeed represents a exact multiple of $N$ and $M$ frames.

So how do I calculate N and M without iterating through all the possible numbers?

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your equation as $$S(N+M) + M =T$$ Now compute $T$ divided by $S$ with a remainder. The remainder is $M$ and the integer result of the division is $N+M$, so you can solve for $N$. Note that this equation in general has lots of solutions but this will give you one solution.

Comment: Right, that works but I guess I have one more constraint which is to find the best possible distribution. So my equation is probably not complete.

Comment: @AlexisWilke Then you need to define what 'best' is. All the solutions to this equation can be found in a similar way so if we know what best is, we can probably pick that one.

Comment: Yes. I will need a _little bit of time_ to find out how to rephrase that one.